# Two way binding not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a template which populates 5 data at a time, that template contains a anchor tag. On click of that I have to populate next 5 data in the same template.

The populating part is being done by backend service. For the first time the data are being populated on load, next time on click of anchor tag I want to populate the content calling backend service.

The problem is that first time the data is being bound with the variable but for the second time it is not getting bound.

loadmorecontroller.js:

```
$http.get('url').success(function(data){
    $scope.test = data;
});

$scope.loadMore = function() {
    $http.get('url').success(function(data){
        $scope.test = data;
    });
}
```

This test variable I am using in html page. For the first call the data is being bound with test but with second (load more) call test is not being updated (when I am checking it in html page).

Comment: Have you checked in devtools for errors and if the network call is being made?

Comment: The network is being called even I am printing the data it is giving me the new result. But its not being populated in the html page.

Comment: Sounds like you are updating a different scope to the one your initial view is bound to. without seeing more of your code it's very hard for us to help. Can you set up a fiddle or plunk that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comments I will try to upload dummy project related to that on fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that you are actually loading any data and that you are not getting unhandled HTTP errors. Eliminating loading an external resource, you can the binding works.

```js
angular.module('app', [])

    .controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

          $scope.data = [];
  
          $timeout(function() {
          
            $scope.data.push('foo');
            
          });             
  
          $scope.loadMore = function() {
          
              $scope.data.push('more');
            
          }

    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="testCtrl"> 
  
  {{data}}
  
  <a ng-click="loadMore()">Load More</a>
  
</div>
```